# Is there a way to retrieve some text from a webpage to a textbox in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make it so I can have several text boxes in my form show pieces of information from a specific webpage.  For example, would there be a way I would be able to retrieve the title of this question to a variable with the click of a button in Visual Basic?

Comment: Look at the related links at the bottom right of the page.

Comment: I meant VB.net.

Comment: See the [WebBrowser.Document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document) class. It's a [HtmlDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument) class, which provides some useful tools: `GetElementById`, `GetElementsByTagName`, `GetElementFromPoint`, for example, plus the pre-build collections of HTML elements: `Links`, `Images`, `Forms` etc. and, should you need it, the `Title` element, representing the HTML page title. The title of this question is `H1` element which contains (`InnerHtml`) an `A` (anchor) element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not hard but you have to look at the source page, and identify the elements.

In nicely formed pages, usually the div elements have a tag ID, but often they don't, so you have to grab say by a attribute name - often you can use the class name of the div in question.

So, to grab the Title, and you question text of this post?

This works:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xDoc As New Xml.XmlDocument

    Dim strURL As String = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753982"

    Dim xWeb As New WebBrowser

    xWeb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    xWeb.Navigate(strURL)
    Do Until xWeb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    Dim HDoc As HtmlDocument = xWeb.Document

    Debug.Print(HDoc.GetElementById("question-header").FirstChild.InnerText)
    Debug.Print(FindClass(HDoc, "post-text"))

End Sub

Function FindClass(Hdoc As HtmlDocument, strClass As String) As String

    ' get all Divs, and search by class name
    Dim OneElement As HtmlElement
    For Each OneElement In Hdoc.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If OneElement.GetAttribute("classname") = strClass Then
            Return OneElement.InnerText
        End If
    Next
    ' we get here, not found, so return a empty stirng
    Return "not found"

End Function
```

OutPut:

(first part is title question)

```
Is there a way to retrieve some text from a webpage to a textbox in VB?
```

(second part is question text)

```
I'm trying to make it so I can have several text boxes in my form show pieces of
information from a specific webpage. For example, would there be a way I would be
able to retrieve the title of this question to a variable with the click of a button
in Visual Basic?
```

Comment: How do we get the id of the textbox?

Comment: How do you get a city from a row of data in Excel? You go look at the Excel sheet. You need to look at the raw HTML of the web page. Most browsers while viewing a page allow you to right click and go view source. (at last that what IE11 has - so each browser will be different). This whole process is a LOT easier if you can at least read and understand some HTML. So, you look the raw HTML of the web page, and then search for the text in question. You usually find the "div" section that has your text or control or whatever it is you are looking for. Some div sections have a "ID" but some don't.

Comment: You can well see that me and the other poster rather quick pointed out the section. So being familiar with some HTML is no different then say being familiar with SQL. Hard to tell you to find something in SQL if you never seen or read SQL. So, same goes for HTML You want to gain  experience using  your standard browser to view the raw HTML - all browsers allow this.